# Test my Framework with a Playground

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode7, swift-playground

I started a personal project a couple weeks ago. For that, I created a Playground and started coding.

Now I'd like to create a Framework out of it in order to use it in future Apps. So, the problem is the following:

I start a new Project in XCode and I make this project a template of Cocoa Touch Framework. My problems arrive when I try to create a Playground to test this project.

Here are the steps I've taken to accomplish this:

1. Create my Framework Project with all the classes it needs.
2. Create a new workspace
3. Create a new playground inside the workspace
4. Drag the .xcodeproj file from the Framework inside the workspace

When I drag the .xcodeproj file into the workspace, it only copies the file (without all classes inside the Framework).

I'm using xcode 7.2 with swift 2.1.1

Thanks for your help :)

PD: to clear out: I'm trying to test the Framework with a Playground

Comment: You should use the .framework file generated under Products.

Comment: The thing is that the framework isn't finished yet so I want to have a playground with the Framework so I can test it.
I've figured out how to have the Framework and a Playground inside a Workspace, the problem now is that the Playground doesn't see the classes inside the Framework :/

Comment: I've done something similar and test it by creating a project in the framework workspace and do my testing there.

Comment: Oh god such a silly thing! I only had to import the project inside the playground! Thank you very much though :)

Comment: that's awesome to know @Carles Mitjans